# Rails vs Ruby namespacing rules.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Reading this really good article on Rails namespacing and module lookup. [Here](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/)

I don't understand what this means:

> If constants are loaded only when they’re first encountered at
>   runtime, then by necessity their load order depends on the individual
>   execution path.

What is the `individual execution path`?

I think that non-understand leads me to not understand this:

> As soon as an already-loaded constant Baz is encountered, Rails knows
>   this cannot be the Baz it is looking for, and the algorithm raises a
>   NameError.

or more importantly this:

> The first time, as before, is down to the loss of nesting information.
>   Rails can’t know that Foo::Qux isn’t what we’re after, so once it
>   realises that Foo::Bar::Qux does not exist, it happily loads it.
>
> The second time, however, Foo::Qux is already loaded. So our reference can’t have been to that constant, otherwise Ruby would have
>   resolved it, and autoloading would never have been invoked. So the
>   lookup terminates with a NameError, even though our reference could
>   (and should) have resolved to the as-yet-unloaded ::Qux.

Why doesn't rails use the constant that is encountered that is already loaded? Also why does running:

```
Foo::Bar.print_qux
```

twice lead to two different outcomes?

Answer (score 1):

By "execution path" they mean the way your code is running. If there's a reference to a class `X::Y` inside an `if` block that isn't executed, that means your execution path bypasses it so it's not loaded.

This is different than force-loading all classes referenced in your code at parse time. They're simply loaded as they're exercised if and only if that given line of code is executed.

The autoloader has a strategy for trying to load modules starting with the most specific and then looking for increasingly global names. `Qux` is tested against the current module context, then the root of that and so on. This is how symbols are resolved.

In that example the auto-loaded version actually pushes the `Foo::Qux` definition ahead of `::Qux` in terms of priority. That's the major change there.